# PHP Regex preg_match_all issues

Tags: php, regex

I have this array and i want to match all ids.

```
Array
(
    [0] => <td><a href="readmail.html?id=xsX321dsa">Hi</a></td>
)
```

I tried this, but it simply returns me an empty result.

```
preg_match_all("#<td><a href=\"readmail.html?id=(.*?)\">#si",$output[0],$match);
```

Does anybody has any idea about this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to escape `?` to match the question mark literally because it has a special meaning in regular expression.

```
preg_match_all("#<td><a href=\"readmail\.html\\?id=(.*?)\">#si",
               $output[0], $match);
```

BTW, If you use `'`, you don't need to escape `"`.

```
preg_match_all('#<td><a href="readmail\.html\?id=(.*?)">#si',
               $output[0], $match);
```

**UPDATE** You should also escape `.`. It matches any character (except newline according to mode).

**UPDATE** Instead of using `\` to escape, you can also use `\Q`, `\E` (metacharacters inside the `\Q` and `\E` are ignored and matched literally):

```
preg_match_all('#<td><a href="readmail\Q.html?\Eid=(.*?)">#si',
               $output[0], $match);
```

Answer (score 1):

dot `.` and question mark `?` have special meaning in regex pattern. You need to escape it.

- `.` matches any character (except newline)
- `?` Quantifier to match between zero and one time, as many times as possible,

It should be using **Non-greedy** way

```
<td><a href="readmail\.html\?id=(.*?)">
```

OR try with [**Character Classes or Character Sets**](http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html)

```
<td><a href="readmail\.html\?id=([^"]+)">
```

Here is [demo1](http://regex101.com/r/dV4fE6/3) and [demo2](http://regex101.com/r/dV4fE6/4)

Sample code:

```
$re = "/<td><a href=\\"readmail\\.html\\?id=([^\\"]+)\\">/";
$str = "<td><a href=\"readmail.html?id=xsX321dsa\">Hi</a></td>";

preg_match_all($re, $str, $matches);
```